# Floating point conversion - Binary -> decimal

Tags: c, binary, floating-point-conversion

Here's the number I'm working on

1 01110 001 = ____
1 sign bit, 5 exp bits, 3 fraction bits
bias = 15

Here's my current process, hopefully you can tell me where I'm missing something

1. Convert binary exponent to decimal
   `01110 = 14`
2. Subtract bias
   `14 - 15 = -1`
3. Multiply fraction bits by result
   `0.001 * 2^-1 = 0.0001`
4. Convert to decimal
   `.0001 = 1/16`

The sign bit is 1 so my result is -1/16, however the given answer is -9/16. Would anyone mind explaining where the extra 8 in the fraction is coming from?

Comment: The first bit is omitted. 001 => (1)001

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32), especially the part that explains that the significand is *"24 bits (23 explicitly stored)"*

Comment: see [Representation and encoding in memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Representation_and_encoding_in_memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the correct concept, including an understanding of the excess-N representation, but you're missing a crucial point.

The 3 bits used to encode the fractional part of the magnitude are `001`, but there is an implicit `1.` preceding the fraction bits, so the full magnitude is actually `1.001`, which can be represented as an improper fraction as `1+1/8 => 9/8`.

`2^(-1)` is the same as `1/(2^1)`, or `1/2`.

`9/8 * 1/2 = 9/16`. Take the sign bit into account, and you arrive at the answer `-9/16`.

Comment: Thank you! I remember reading about the implicit 1. Just to make sure, the implicit 1 is used when any of the exponent bits are 1 correct? If they were all zeros there would be no implicit 1

Comment: @jlee Yes, that is correct. See [Exponent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding) for more info, assuming your encoding is similar to the IEEE 754 binary encodings.

Comment: @jlee Also when "they (exponent bits) were all zeros", code does not use `0-bias`, but `1-bias` to get the true exponent.

Answer (score 2):

For normalized floating point representation, the **Mantissa** (fractional bits) = 1 + f. This is sometimes called an implied leading 1 representation. This is a trick for getting an additional bit of precision for free since we can always adjust the exponent E so that significant M is in the range 1<=M < 2 ...

You are almost correct but must take into consideration the implied 1.  If it is **denormalized** (meaning the exponent bits are all 0s) you do not add an implied 1.

I would solve this problem as such...

```
1  01110  001

bias = 2^(k-1) -1 =        14

Exponent = e - bias       

14 - 15 = -1
```

1. Take the fractional bits  ->> 001
2. Add the implied 1  ->> 1.001
3. Shift it by the exponent, which is -1. Becomes .1001
4. Count up the values, 1(1/2) + 0(1/4) + 0(1/8) + 1(1/16) = 9/16
5. With the a negative sign bit it becomes -9/16

hope that helps!